# How to print these outputs on the same line?

Tags: python, random, printing, range, line

The code is this:

```
for i in range(0, 20):
        print(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation))
```

Alas, it prints each character on a new line. How do I make them print on one?

Comment: `print("...", end="")` (Assuming Python 3) or `sys.stdout.write("...")`

Comment: In case of python 2.7 put, at the end of the expression.  print var,

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- `print(..)` has an `end` argument. If you set it to the empty string, it does **not** print the newline.

  So:

  ```
  options = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

  for i in range(0, 20):
      print(random.choice(options),end='')
  ```

  (I introduced a variable `options` to make it more readable)
- you can first construct the entire result with `''.join()` and print that:

  ```
  print(''.join(random.choice(options) for _ in range(20)))
  ```

  here the `<expr> for <var> in <iterable>` is a generator: it will generate 20 random values (out of the `options`) and join them together.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a expression like this:

```
chars = [random.choice(options) for _ in range(20)]
```

and simply print the chars afterwards:

```
print(chars)
```

generated output might look like this:

```
[6, 9, 5, 79, 78, 9, 2, 7, 9, 3, 3, 7, 9, 9, 6, 5, 78, 79, 5, 78]
```

given such an options:

```
options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] + [9,78,9,78,79,98,7]
```